# How to use my view controllers and other class in the Share Extension ? iOS | Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

I am creating a chatting application. User can share the images from other application to my application. I have added Share Extension to show my app in the native share app list. I'm also getting the selected data in didSelectPost Method. From here I want to show the list of the users to whom the image can be forwarded. For this, I'm using an already created view controller in the main app target.

```
 override func didSelectPost() {
        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.

        if let content = self.extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem {
            let contentType = kUTTypeImage as String

            // Verify the provider is valid
            if let contents = content.attachments as? [NSItemProvider] {
                for attachment in contents {
                    if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentType) {
                        attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType, options: nil) { (data, error) in
                            let url = data as! URL
                            let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
                            // Here I'm navigating to my viewcontroller, let's say: ForwardVC
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't want to recreate the same screen in Share Extension. Apart from this view controllers, I have many more classes and wrappers that I want to use within the share extension. Like, SocketManager, Webservices, etc. Please suggest me your approach to achieve the same.

**P.S.:** I've tried setting multiple targets to required viewControllers and using same pods for Share Extention. In this approach, I'm facing a lot of issues as many of the methods and pods are not extention compliant. Also, is it the right way to do this.

Comment: create framework